# why does my form submission not work?

Tags: angularjs

I just want to use the two way binding to update my list by adding new elements to it. I don't understand why i can't do it? am i missing a major concept?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>NgRailsTodoList</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body ng-app="todoApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="content-container clearfix">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 class="content-title text-center">Todo</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="list in lists">
          <h3>{{list.name}}</h3>
          <div ng-repeat="task in list.tasks">
            <h5><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="task.completed">{{ task.body }}</h5>
          </div>
        <div>
      </div>
      <form ng-submit="addList()">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name"></input>
        <button type="submit"> New List </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('todoApp', ['ui.router', 'templates'])
.factory('lists',[ function () {
  var o = { lists: [{ name: "groceries", completed: false,
                    tasks: [{body: "buy fish",completed: true},
                            {body: "buy sushi",completed: false},
                            {body: "buy bread",completed: true}]}]
          };
  return o;
}])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
  '$scope','lists',
   function($scope,lists){
     console.log(lists);
     $scope.lists = lists.lists;
     $scope.addList = function(){
       $scope.lists.push({name: $scope.name, completed: false})
       // console.log(this.name);
       // $scope.name = '';
     };
   }
 ]);
```

Comment: What error you got in console ?

Comment: What specifically is not working and what is the desired outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the markup.
`<h5><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="task.completed">{{ task.body }}</h5>
      </div>
    <div>
  </div>`

the second `<div>` should be a close tag `</div>`

here is a working example http://codepen.io/mkl/pen/KzEmwP